# C++ symbol export for class extending template class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, linker

I'm working on a C++ project built with Visual Studio 2008.
I'm defining (in a project producing a dll) a template class and a derived, not-template, one:

```
template <class T>
struct DLL_EXPORT Base {
  int base() { return 1; }
};

struct DLL_EXPORT Deriv: public Base<Deriv> {
  int deriv() { return 1; }
};
```

the `DLL_EXPORT` is the usual stuff:

```
#ifdef COMPILING_MY_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Now, when I'm trying to use my `Deriv` class in another project, the trouble is starting. If I use only the function from `Deriv`, it works well:

```
Deriv d;
d.deriv();
```

But if I try to call `d.base()`, I get the following linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall Base<struct Deriv>::base(void)" (__imp_?base@?$Base@UDeriv@@@@QAEHXZ)
```

If, elsewhere in my dll code, I'm using the d.base() function, it works well, and the linker error disappear in the "user" project. And if I remove the template part (it's not really useful in my example, but in the real-life situation it is), everything is fine.

It looks like the function don't get compiled if it's not used, or something equivalent. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about this, but I think you might be able to fix it by writing

```
template struct Base<Derive>;
```

somewhere in your source file. (or perhaps `template DLL_EXPORT struct Base<Derive>;`)

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks. The DLL_EXPORT is not needed, and you can even just say `template Base<Deriv>` (without the struct keyword)

Answer (score 4):

don't use __declspec(dllexport) on template definitions since they are not exported (they are not real code until instantiated).
They are only in the header file for usage by sources. You can use __declspec(dllexport) on specializations of templates ,but you must instatiated those at least once in your DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, even though it does not fix the problem, I haven't thought of that.

Comment: For the poor soul coming here : this answer may solve your problem if using MinGW. Whatever you do in the subclass / DLL, you *will* have a link time error if the Base template class has `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Answer (score 3):

If that is your problem, you might be able to fix it by [explicitly instantiating the template](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/topic/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc16explicit_instantiation.htm#HDREXPLICIT_INSTANTIATION).

In one of the .cc files in your DLL (not header file), include your template definition and write:

```
template int Base<Deriv>::base();
```

This should force the compiler to put the code for `Base<Deriv>::base()` into that compilation unit so your linker can find it.

Comment: i'm not sure of it ,but i think this will not export the name Base<Deriv>::base()

Comment: @Edwin: I would be curious to know.  The class is being declared "dllexport", so the compiler might do the Right Thing here.

Comment: you were 100% right. Put your suggestion in a dll source and it linked OK. (didn't expect that)

Comment: This one works, but as I do have several methods in my base class, the answer by karadoc is more efficient : you can explicitly instantiate a whole class at once